# Best way to organise point data before parsing it into a netCDF using netCDF4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

I have over 300 sites where i have hourly precipitation data all starting and ending at different, all stored on separate xlsx files (site data files). I have a seperate xlsx file (directory file) with the site data filename, longitude and latitude on. i want to parse this data into a blank netcdf. what is the best way to organise this data?

This is what the original xlsx spreadsheets look like:

Directory file (Dir_F):

[image: Directory file]

Individual site data files:

[image]

How I have organised my data in arrays as follows

latitude

```
lat = DIR_F['Latitude'].values
In[1]: lat.shape
Out[1]: (400,)
```

Longitude

```
lon= DIR_F['Longitude'].values
In[1]: lon.shape
Out[1]: (400,)
```

(please note there are 400 sites)

I have ran some code which concatenates all 400 sites together, keeping all dates and times. This has given me a dataframe which the first column is time (hourly) and the next 400 columns is precipitation data with the site name as the column header. From this dataframe (DF_ALL) i have got both time and precipitation arrays, as follows:

#### Time:

```
time = DF_ALL['Time'].values
in[2]: time.shape
out[2]: (33867,)
```

#### Precipitation

```
DF_precip = DF_ALL
del DF_precip['Time']
DF_precip = DF_precip.to.numpy()
in[3]: DF_precip.shape
out[3]: (33867, 400)
```

With this data I am following tutorials including (https://unidata.github.io/python-training/workshop/Bonus/netcdf-writing/ and https://pyhogs.github.io/intro_netcdf4.html) for creating a netCDF with netCDF4 and im getting various errors and blank netCDFs.

I have created a blank netCDF, specified dimensions and built variables as follows:

#### creating blank netCDF

```
import netCDF4 as nc4
f = nc4.Dataset('precip.nc','w', format='NETCDF4')

precip_group = f.createGroup('Precip_data')
```

#### Speciffying dimensions

```
precip_group.createDimension('lon', len(lon))
precip_group.createDimension('lat', len(lat))
precip_group.createDimension('time', None))
```

#### Building variables

```
longitude = precip_group.createVariable('Longitude', 'f4', 'lon')
latitude = precip_group.createVariable('Latitude', 'f4', 'lat')
precip = precip_group.createVariable('Precip', 'f4', ('time', 'lon', 'lat'))
time = precip_group.createVariable('Time', 'i4', 'time')
```

#### passing the data into the variables

```
longitude[:] = lon 
latitude[:] = lat
precip[0,:,:] = DF_precip
```

When i try this i get the error "array() takes no arguments (1 given)" for "longitude[:] = lon".

i have also tried to use the time variable as a none unlimited dimension, as follows:

```
precip_group.createDimension('time', len(time)

time = precip_group.createVariable('Time', 'f4', 'time')

time[:] = time
```

this has given me a blank netCDF when running it.

#### Summary

How to best organise point data in dataframes before passing it into a netCDF? This could be by any module including xarray, iris, netCDF4 ect.

Comment: please include what you have tried.

Comment: @parlad Sure, have done

Comment: You can follow the CF convention for discrete sampling geometries. More info at: http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.8/cf-conventions.html#discrete-sampling-geometries

Comment: I think it's worth giving xarray a shot here. if you have data with time in the rows and location in the columns, you can call `df.stack().to_xarray()` to dump the data into a DataArray. See the [xarray docs on working with pandas](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/pandas.html) and the [`pandas.DataFrame.to_xarray`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xarray.html) docs for more info.